# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'nlargest'

Tags: python, pandas

**What does this error: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'nlargest' mean?**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('persons-arrested-for-selected-major-offences-by-age-group.csv', index_col="level_1")
df2 = df.dropna()

df_year = df2[df2['year']==2018]
df_age = df_year[df_year['level_2']=='21 Years Old And Below']

df_offences = df_age.drop_duplicates().sort_values('level_1', ascending=False)
df_offences.plot.bar(figsize = (15,6)).nlargest(3,['level_1','value'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Im trying to have the top three values in offences show

Comment: Then you should do `df_offenses.nlargest(...).plot.bar(...)`?